# Encoding issue windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio, encoding

In my new laptop I copied and try to open an existing in anothes laptop file in visual studio 2017. The problem is the greek characters as shown in the image
[image]

The left side is from the file opened in visual studio with some strange characters, while in the right side, the same file opened in notepad has the correct characters.
I don't know if this is a problem of windows10, visual studio or anything else. Any ideas what setting I must look and change?

Comment: `'ΝΕΕΣ'` string saved using _Greek_ encoding `ANSI 1253`  results to a byte sequence `0xCD`,`0xC5`,`0xC5`,`0xD3` in a file. Reading the same file using _US & Western Eu_ encoding `ANSI 1252`  results to a string `'ÍÅÅÓ'`. Flagrant [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case.

Comment: Thank you @JosefZ, your answer gave me the right path. I changed the language locale as described here http://www.digitalcitizen.life/changing-display-language-used-non-unicode-programs?page=1 and everything works fine again!

Comment: Changing the locale is not a solution. You need to switch to a character encoding that is immune to local system settings, like UTF-8. See [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).

Answer (score 0):

Save the file in **UTF8 encoding**. Then you won't have to change the locale on new a laptop.

In Visual Studio you can do it from the File menu by clicking "Save with encoding".

[How to: Save and Open Files with Encoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxfdkfke.aspx)